# How to determine meta-fields in my database design?

Tags: database-design

I'm working on a very large dataset and I want to create a metatable that contains metadata about columns in the dataset.

For example, for an `int` column, I might want `total`, `max-value`, `average-value`, `min-value`, etcetera. So, a column "age" with millions of age records would have a meta-table that contains:

```
total = 1000000
max-value = 110
min-value = 4
average-value = 32
etcetera...
```

I have `int`, `boolean`, `string`, `date`, `float` and `date` columns.

**Question**:
Where can I find / what would be a list with basic metadata for such fields? *Or* what can I do more than the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From statistical point of view, `int` and `float` are typical dependent variables (Y axis on charts). For those (on given set) you calculate statistical values like arithmetic/geometric mean, median, standard deviation, variance, etc.

`string`, `boolean` and `date` are typically independent variables (or regressors - X  axis on charts). As such, they are not supposed to be described. Technically, you can calculate a median on a set of boolean values or dates (you may consider them dependent), but it does not make much sense generally. On string columns, you could calculate an average length of string, number of different characters used in a string or even count uppercase/lowercase letters. But I really don't think such information would be of use to anyone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Boris. This is helpful and your comments do make sense.